# remove attachments

Tags: gmail

Attachments are shown like this at the bottom of the mail...

```
3 attachments — Download all attachments  
    Summary_JUNE2012_02057.pdf
12K   View Download  
    S_NO_XXXXXX5_02012_03223.pdf
12K   View Download  
    important.pdf
73K   View Download
```

how do I remove all the attachments but keep the mail?
I will like to have only the mail text archived and not the attachments.
This will help me to save the space without loosing the text that is important in some cases than the files attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got only one way to do that.Forward the same email to yourself without attachment and then delete the previous email which has attachment.